# Failed to initialize Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, charts, containers, jenkins-plugins

Any idea about this Error?
I'm getting this Error in Jenkins Pods startup in GKE Cluster:

Docker image used Latest from

```
 NAME      CREATED                IMAGE
jenkins   2021-02-13T15:31:20Z   jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

GKE Cluster:1.16.15-gke.6000
Node Pool Version:1.15.12-gke.20
Helm chart:https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins

```
2021-02-13 15:36:26.958+0000 [id=27]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed ConfigurationAsCode.init
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No hudson.slaves.Cloud implementation found for kubernetes
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$lookupDescriptor$11(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:211)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(Option.java:321)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lookupDescriptor(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:210)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$configure$3(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:84)
    at io.vavr.Tuple2.apply(Tuple2.java:238)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.configure(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:83)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:92)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.check(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:55)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.configure(BaseConfigurator.java:344)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.BaseConfigurator.check(BaseConfigurator.java:287)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.lambda$checkWith$8(ConfigurationAsCode.java:753)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:689)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:753)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:738)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:614)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:298)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:290)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:104)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:110)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:175)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:296)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1131)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:214)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-13 15:36:26.960+0000 [id=20]    SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No hudson.slaves.Cloud implementation found for kubernetes
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.impl.configurators.HeteroDescribableConfigurator.lambda$lookupDescriptor$11(HeteroDescribableConfigurator.java:211)
    at io.vavr.control.Option.orElse(Option.java:321) 

enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after upgrading the jenkins chart version to 3.1.8 .
After upgrading to 3.1.9 the error has been fixed.

They seem to fix the configurations that were causing the error in the new version.
https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/compare/jenkins-3.1.8...jenkins-3.1.9

requirements.yaml

```
- name: "jenkins"
  condition: jenkins.enabled
  version: "3.1.9"
  repository:  "https://charts.jenkins.io"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all u need to change your chart repo, take this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts
After try re-deploy your jenkins without pvc and plugins.
I got same issue and jenkins started after changed version on plugin:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/releases
I changed version from v1.46 to v1.47 and jenkins version from 2.263.4 to 2.279
For this use different tag from your jenkins/jenkins:lts to jenkins/jenkins it will take 2.279 or later

After this changes my jenkins get up